# Invoke external script using Autotools

Tags: autotools, automake

I am using Autotools, and trying to get `configure.ac` and the resulting `configure` script to call an external `build_library.sh` script.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`configure.ac` is just a shell script with a "few" macros added on top of it. So, you can put any shell code in there:

```
$ac_top_srcdir/build_library.sh
```

(The `$ac_top_srcdir` makes sure that your script can be found even if you are running `./configure` from another directory.)

Comment: follow-up question: now configure calls the desired build library script. However, when checking if the library exists (the build was successful), configure can't find the file, even though it is there.. Do I need to refresh file structure or something?

Comment: Check that you are looking in the correct directory. (configure may have changed to another one.) If that's not it, please consider opening a new question - comments aren't the place to ask follow-up questions, because they're not findable by someone else with the same problem in the future.