# Run a script during the run of configure

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I have a project QPhiX that uses GNU Autotools. There is a very related project called QPhiX-Codegen that is needed by the former. The overall build process works like this:

1. Run `make` in QPhiX-Codegen. That will compile the code generator and run it. While running, it will create flat C++ code.
2. Run a Python script that uses a template engine to wrap that flat C++ code into full header and source code files. That will also create a `CMakeLists.txt` such that the generated code can be compiled.
3. Run `cmake` and `make` on the `Makefile` generated by `cmake` to compile the generated code into a static library, `libqphix_codegen.a`.

These three things are wrapped up in a Bash script that one calls with `./generate-and-compile $isa $cxx $cxxflags`. The ISA could be `AVX2`, the C++ compiler could me `mpiicpc`.

Then one switches the directories to QPhiX and continues the build process:

4. Run `./configure ... --enable-arch=ISA --with-codegen=path/to/codegen/directory CXX=$CXX CXXFLAGS=$CXXFLAGS` to create the `Makefile`. In that `Makefile`, it will have the needed compiler flags to include the generated header files and link to `libqphix_codegen.a`.
5. Run `make` on the `Makefile` generated by `./configure`.

This process exposes more steps to the user than really needed. Also the user has to pass the same ISA flag, the same `CXX` and the same `CXXFLAGS` to two different scripts. Then they also have to put in this path to the code generator into the `./configure`.

I think it would be most convenient for the user to have the code generator a git submodule in the QPhiX project. Then the `./configure` could just run the `codegen/generate-and-compile` script and pass the options to it.

My question is: How would I run a script in the `./configure`? Do I just put the snippet I want into `configure.ac`? That file *looks* like a shell script with some macros, but I am not sure whether that would be the right spot to put it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke external script using Autotools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26757929/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This process exposes more steps to the user than really needed. Also
>   the user has to pass the same ISA flag, the same `CXX` and the same
>   `CXXFLAGS` to two different scripts. Then they also have to put in this
>   path to the code generator into the `./configure`.

Those are valid criticisms.  The quickest and easiest way to address them would probably be to write a small wrapper script.  But you ask,

> How would I run a script in the `./configure`? Do I just
>   put the snippet I want into `configure.ac`? That file *looks* like a shell
>   script with some macros, but I am not sure whether that would be the
>   right spot to put it.

`configure.ac` is input for the `m4` macro processor, drawing on special configuration and a library of macros provided by the Autotools and possibly other sources.  Autoconf processes it with `m4` to produce the `configure` shell script.

Ultimately, then, if you want `configure` to run an external command (e.g. another script), you must either write that command directly in `configure.ac` (which indeed you can do) or use a macro that will cause the command to be emitted into the output script.  There is no built-in, general-purpose macro for that.  You have to take a bit of care to avoid or escape syntax that `m4` will try to interpret, but it can be done.  Indeed, the macro library contains several examples of macros that expand to external commands, such as commands to run the compiler.

On the other hand, `configure` operates by gathering information and writing and launching *another* script, `config.status`.  You have the option of causing `configure` to emit the commands you want run into `config.status`; you would do this via the second and / or third argument to [`AC_CONFIG_FILES`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Configuration-Actions.html#Configuration-Actions).

On the third hand, updating the main project's configuration script to automatically incorporate code generation via the other project effectively merges the two projects together.  If I were going to do that then I'd be inclined to perform a much deeper merging than you seem to be proposing.  Configuration should, really, be limited to preparing suitable Makefiles.  All the code generation and building would be better handled by one (possibly recursive) `make` run.  I don't see any reason to think that that could not be achieved in your case, but setting it up would involve more work.

Comment: It seems like I better cal the sub-project script from `make`. How would I add a target to the main `Makefile` such that everything else depends on that target?